# Colorizing the route path in networkx

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I'm trying to draw a different route paths using python networkx library but each has a different color. For example I have the below route data

```
node_list = [('Route_4', '84.80.12.90', '84.80.3.53')

,('Route_12', '84.80.12.90', '84.80.3.94', '84.80.3.57')

,('Route_3', '84.80.66.38', '84.80.3.57')

,('Route_9', '84.80.66.38', '84.80.3.5', '84.80.3.53')

,('Route_8', '84.80.12.90', '84.80.3.12')]
```

Each element represent a separate node and I need to draw them such that each whole route(that may contain 3 or 4 nodes) has a different color from the other route. I created the below code and able to plot the nodes on the graph, however I couldn't find an option to colorize the route path

```
for node_tuple in range(len(node_list)):
    G.add_path(tuple(node_list[node_tuple]))
pos = nx.shell_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos,edge_color='red')
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `draw_networkx_edges`?  It has an option to say which edges to draw.

Comment: Yes I used this option in my provided code[edge_color] and give it a list of color, however I need to mark the whole path not only specific edges given that edges are automatically generated with add_path() method

Comment: I'm not sure what your challenge is.  You seem to have a list of the edges.  There is an option in `draw_networkx_edges` that lets you tell it what edges you want.  Then you use `edge_color` to tell it what color you want those edges to be.  To give more help, I'll need an [mcve] so that I can just copy and paste your code and see what you're getting.